# How to integrate angular js with asp.net 2017 MVC core?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I'm developing a simple web application using ***Asp.net MVC Core (2017)*** and ***angular***.
This is the script code in head section with controller: (**Note:** The 'Scripts' folder is in wwwroot, which have angular.min.js)

```
<script src="~/Scripts/angular.min.js" type="text/javascript">
    var app = angular.module("moduleName", []).controller(function ($scope) {
        $scope.message = "hello world";

    });
</script>
```

This is the div in body section:

```
<div ng-app="moduleName">{{message}}</div>
```

At run-time it is throwing error:

```
JavaScript runtime error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.9/$injector/modulerr?p0=moduleName&p1=Error%3A%20%5B%24injector%3Anomod%
```

Even I tried using the solution from a stack-overflow question:
[AngularJS 0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: [$injector:modulerr]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27141607/angularjs-0x800a139e-javascript-runtime-error-injectormodulerr). But it didn't worked.

What must be the solution for this error???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Close the angular js `script` tag

```
<script src="~/Scripts/angular.min.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
<script>
    var app = angular.module("moduleName", []).controller(function ($scope) {
        $scope.message = "hello world";

    });
<script>
```

Give the name to controller:

```
<script>
        var app = angular.module("moduleName", []);
        app.controller('firstCtrl',function ($scope) {
            $scope.message = "hello world";

        });
    <script>
```

**HTML**:

```
  <div ng-app="moduleName">
    <div ng-controller='firstCtrl'>.....
       {{message }}
    ...
   </div>
</div>
```